# Functions from an imported module are not available in a powershell script

Tags: powershell, module, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I am working with PowerShell V 4.0 on a Windows Server machine. I have encountered a problem that I am not able to debug or find a solution.

I have a ps1 script that imports two psm1 modules A and B. (B in turn imports another module C).

```
Import-Module  $PSScriptRoot\..\lib\infra\moduleA.psm1 
Import-Module  $PSScriptRoot\..\lib\nwm\moduleB.psm1 

#get-logger function works fine. This is defined in moduleA
$log = get-logger

$smisXmlData = [xml] $smisConfigData

#The function get-hostLocalCred is defined in moduleB. This is where the error occurs. 
($username, $password) = get-hostLocalCred $smisXmlData
```

I am not able to use the functions from the second module moduleB in the script. When I run the script, it throws errors where ever a function from the module B is used. The error is below (get-hostLocalCred is the function name.)

```
get-hostLocalCred : The term 'get-hostLocalCred' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling  of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
```

The following is the content in the moduleB.

```
#Importing moduleC. 
Import-Module  $PSScriptRoot/../infra/moduleC.psm1

#Defining required functions. These are the functions that are not available in the above script. 
function get-hostLocalCred {
    Param($xmldata)
    $log.entry()
    $username = $xmldata.component.yourhost.localcred.username
    $log.debug("USERNAME: $username")
    $password = $xmldata.component.yourhost.localcred.password
    $log.exit()
    return $username, $password
}

function new-ArrayCredObj {
Param([Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $user,
  [Parameter(Mandatory = $true)] $password)
    $log.entry()
    $log.info("Creating custom Object")
    $log.debug("User : $user")
    $log.debug("Pwd : $password")
    $arrayCred = New-Object psobject
    $arrayCred | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name auser -Value $user
    $arrayCred | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name password -Value $password
    $log.exit()
    return $arrayCred
}
.
.
.
.
```

The functions from moduleA are being executed properly, but I am not able to execute the function from moduleB. 
Also, After running the script in the console, When I try to lookup the functions available in the Module B, using the following commandlet,

```
Get-Command -Module ModuleB
```

I only see the functions defined in the ModuleC, which is imported by moduleB, but I donot see any of the functions defined in the moduleB. I have been working with powershell but this is the first time I have seen this issue.

When I do a Get-Module, I see only moduleA and moduleB.

All the Modules are imported in the following way:

```
Import-Module  $PSScriptRoot/../lib/newmodules/moduleB.psm1
```

Importing modules Globally has also not solved the problem.

Importing modules by giving actual path like following has also not solved the issue.

```
Import-Module C:\folderpath\ModuleB.psm1
```

All the functions in all the modules have been defined as following. There is no difference in the function definition in any of the modules.

```
function get-hostLocalCred {
    Param($xmldata)
    # Function Definition 
    return $result
}
```

I might be missing a simple thing but I am not able to get it. I have been importing modules normally and working with them since long time but this is the first time I ran into this issue. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Can you provide [mcve]? It is hard to say anything without repro case.

Comment: @PetSerAl: Sorry about the brief code. I have added some part of the script and module.

Comment: Do you have Export-ModuleMember calls in ModuleB?

Comment: @MikeShepard: No, I donot have them. I have added export-modulemember -function get-hostLocalCred after the function definition in moduleB. but that didnot help. The error messages remain the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem occurs when your manifest (.psd1) does not have a root module specified.

```
@{

# Script module or binary module file associated with this manifest.
RootModule = 'mymodule.psm1' 
...
```

Previously, it would have been commented out by default when generating it from New-ModuleManifest

```
@{

# Script module or binary module file associated with this manifest.
# RootModule = '' 
...
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you are updating the code in moduleB while testing it from a PS session.

Then according to [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/import-module?view=powershell-7#example-8--reimport-a-module-into-the-same-session) you should use the Force parameter of Import-Module if your module has changed during the same calling session.

```
Import-Module $PSScriptRoot\..\lib\nwm\moduleB.psm1 -Force
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I was **re-** importing the `moduele.psm1` into the ISE and powershell noticed it had already been imported so didn't import it again. Even after I had edited the file.

The sam happens in a powershell console session if you didnt exit and restart before re-importing,

Ie:

1. (works) edit file
2. (works) import
3. (works) edit file again
4. (doesnt work) import

I had to do a `Remove-Module modulename` before my re-import with `Import-Module` for it to see my edits, including my new functions.

Answer (score -2):

I had similar issue and it worked by adding "-Scope Global" to import-module cmdlet

Comment: This worked for me as well.